# Combining a Canvas and OpenGL ES Renderer?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, canvas, rendering

I have an app that uses a Class with an extension SurfaceView to draw to a canvas, but i'm looking at moving over to openGL. I noticed that if I merely change the SurfaceView extension to a GLSurfaceView, the app still runs the same. I've also been able to start basic drawing in another app using openGL ES.

I took it the next step and instantiated another class for the renderer in GLSurfaceView, and I instruct the render to draw a triangle. This all compiles and runs fine, but it runs exactly like the original App, with no triangle rendered, but the rest of the canvas draws properly.

I can't think of why it's not rendering, or why it wouldn't render. Or maybe it is rendering, but it's simply being overridden by the canvas?

I know it seems odd to try to use both methods, Since my app is live, I would rather implement switching the rendering over to GL at my own pace so that it doesn't take me a month to get the next update out.

So Anybody ever tried do do this? Run a Gl renderer OVER a canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use both OpenGL and a Canvas to render on a single SurfaceView. You can however put another View on top of the SurfaceView to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like a good way to start. Question, how does that concept work with the setContentView() method?

Comment: What if you have only a `Surface` to render on, like in `WallpaperService`? Is there a way to use OpenGL ES for some parts, and then do the rest with Canvas APIs, targeting the same surface?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
addContentView(SurfaceView);
addContentView(GLSurfaceView);
```

or create a relative layout with both views.

Answer (score 2):

Here my sample code when adding canvas **over** the OpenGL view, thanks to @Audrius Butkevicius !

```
mGLView = new MyOpenGLSurfaceView;
// SET OpenGL View
setContentView(myOpenGLView);


mCanvasOverlayView = new View(context)
mOverlayViewParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
// ADD Canvas view overlay
addContentView(mCanvasOverlayView, mOverlayViewParams );
```